Comparing changes between two time points in ecological survey data with different survey methods
I’m working on analyzing some underwater ecological survey data, and I’m hoping to get some advice on the best statistical approach. The surveys were conducted at the same sites in 2009 and 2024, so I have data from two time points. My goal is to understand the change in benthic cover over time and how environmental factors like depth, exposure, and sedimentation might be influencing these changes.
There is one important thing to note: the 2009 survey used line intercept methods, while the 2024 survey used point intercept method. I’m concerned about how to ensure the data from these different methods are comparable.
Given these factors, what statistical test would you recommend for analyzing this data, considering the environmental variables as potential predictors? Any tips on handling the difference in survey methods would be greatly appreciated too!
Thanks so much for your help!
